# Utilização do Like no elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Estou utilizando o elasticsearch na versão 8.4 com o PHP. Criei um índice chamado artigos e ele tem os mesmos registros presente na tabela do banco de dados.

Preciso simular uma busca com o elasticsearch de forma que traga os mesmos resultados que uma query no SQL faria:

```
SELECT * 
FROM artigos 
WHERE titulo LIKE '%Atualização%'
```

Porém, os resultados não são os mesmos que os obtidos no PHP utilizando o elasticsearch. O código PHP segue abaixo:

```
<?php 
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHosts(['localhost:9200'])
    ->setBasicAuthentication('elastic','secret')
    ->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'artigos',
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 5000,
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'titulo' => 'Atualização'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

if (!empty($results['hits']['hits']))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results['hits']['hits']);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

No lugar do índice 'match' tentei utilizar 'wildcards' e 'regexp', porém também não obtive sucesso.

Li essas duas partes da documentação do elasticsearch para tentar obter os resultados:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-like-rlike-operators.html#sql-like-operator
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/8.4/search_operations.html

Tem alguma forma de fazer com que a busca no PHP fique semelhante a dos resultados obtidos no SQL?

OBS.: Ao fazer o 'mapping', defini o analyzer do campo 'titulo' com o valor 'portuguese'

Comment: poderia trocar o match por `match_phrase`. [Documentação relacionada](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html)

Comment: Olá :) Eu vou testar com esse match_pharse e comparar os resultados.

Answer (score -2):

Em casos como esse eu gosto de usar o query passando como parâmetro o a palavra desejada entre asteriscos confome demonstro no exemplo abaixo. Uma opção legal é usar o parâmetro fuzziness.

```
{
   "query":{
      "query_string":{
         "query":"*Atualização*",
         "fields":[
            "titulo",
            "resumo"
         ],
         "fuzziness":1
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10
}
```

Links para estudo;
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-like-rlike-operators.html